# how to set different pattern on each wall with mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

1. I use fill-extrusion layer to add building on the map, but how to paint the wall with different color/pattern?
2. i try to use self-host sprite, but failed, according to chrome developer tool, sprite@2x.json,sprite@2x.png loaded success.

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: {
        "version": 8,
        sprite: "http://localhost:8000/map/sprite",
        sources: {
          maine: {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {
              'type': 'FeatureCollection',
              'features': [{
                'type': 'Feature',
                'id': 1,
                'geometry': {
                  'type': 'Polygon',
                  'coordinates': [
                    [
                      [-68.13534351262877, 45.137451890638886],
                      [-68.13334151262877, 45.137451890638886],
                      [-68.13334151262877, 45.139421890638886],
                      [-68.13534351262877, 45.139421890638886],
                      [-68.13534351262877, 45.137451890638886]
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "properties": {
                  "height": 60,
                  "min_height": 30
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        layers: [{
          'id': 'maine2',
          'source': 'maine',
          'layout': {},
          "type": "fill-extrusion",
          'paint': {
            'fill-extrusion-color': '#f00',
              'fill-extrusion-pattern': 'wall',
            'fill-extrusion-height': {
              'type': 'identity',
              'property': 'height'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-base': {
              'type': 'identity',
              'property': 'min_height'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-opacity': 1
          }
        }]
      },
      center: [-68.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886],
      zoom: 15,
      pitch: 60,
    });
```

more details about question 2:
[image]

sprite@2x.json, sprite@2x.png loaded success, but nothing show on the screen, but it shows a red cube when i comment the fill-extrusion-pattern line

Answer (score 0):

> I use fill-extrusion layer to add building on the map, but how to paint the wall with different color/pattern?

This is not possible with Mapbox-GL-JS.

(You should post your other question separately, with more details.)

Comment: thanks, Steve. I add some details about question 2.  Back to question 1,  any advice with or without mapbox-gl-js, thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't ask two unrelated questions in one question. Remove your question 2 from here, and create a new question with it.